# Resize commentbox picture size in VBa excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

When I record a macro I get

```
Range("C1").Select 
Range("C1").AddComment 
Range("C1").Comment.Text Text:="Blabla" 
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 2.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 23.1, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

Running this code results in :

> Runtime error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Comment` directly:

```
With Range("C1")
    .AddComment Text:="Blabla"
    With .Comment.Shape
        .ScaleHeight 2.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleWidth 23.1, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Rory thanks, maybe you can answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518872/excel-2013-format-comment-tab-size-press-reset-button-with-vba?noredirect=1#comment56779121_34518872 ?  or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519945/excel-2013-vba-get-picture-in-comment-height

Comment: Per Help: "You can specify msoTrue for this argument only if the specified shape is a picture or an OLE object."

Comment: But you aren't scaling the picture, you're scaling the comment. The picture is merely a background fill and not accessible as a separate object.

Comment: So not possible to get embed picture default sizes? How this size restoring when by reset button?

Comment: Not everything in Excel is exposed to VBA unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Same with Rory.
I add clearcomments first before add comment to avoid an error if a comment already exist.

```
Sub AddCommentAndResize()

With Range("C1")
    .ClearComments
    .AddComment Text:="Blabla"
    With .Comment.Shape
        .ScaleHeight 2.3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        .ScaleWidth 23.1, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code useful when resizing comment boxes.  This doesn't help resolve the original problem, but it fits better with the title of this post.  You simply change the `MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH` to any value.  I have it set to `250`.

```
Sub AutoSizeCommentInSelectedCell()
    Dim cellComment As Comment  ' selected cell
    Dim area As Double          ' comment rectangle area
    Dim n As Integer, vS As Variant
    Dim myMax As Integer, base As Single, rowLen As Integer
    Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim vR(), rowCnt As Integer, myHeight As Single

    Set Wf = WorksheetFunction

    Const MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH = 250

    ' Make sure we have a seected cell.
    If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Make sure we have a comment in the selected cell.
    Set cellComment = ActiveCell.Comment

    If cellComment Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With cellComment
        'myLen = Len(.Text)

        vS = Split(.Text, Chr(10))
        ReDim vR(UBound(vS))
        For I = 0 To UBound(vS)
            vR(I) = Len(vS(I))
        Next I
        myMax = Wf.Max(vR)
        n = UBound(vS)
        ' AutoSize will covert comment to a single line.
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        ' If comment's width is shorter than max, we're done.
        With .Shape
            base = .Height / (n + 1)
            rowLen = Wf.RoundDown(myMax * (MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH / .Width), 0) 'row character's length when width at max
            rowLen = rowLen - rowLen * 0.1 '<~~line character's number  is more small.
            For I = 0 To n
                If Len(vS(I)) = 0 Then
                    rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
                Else
                    rowCnt = rowCnt + Wf.RoundUp(Len(vS(I)) / rowLen, 0)
                End If
            Next I
            myHeight = rowCnt * base

            If .Width < MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            .Width = MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH
            .Height = myHeight
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Source: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156276/how-to-auto-size-excel-comment)