# How to auto-size Excel comment?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to make a **comment popup** in an Excel cell to **auto-size**. Just using the `AutoSize` property is not acceptable, because it converts the comment to a **single line**. Here is my idea:

- Set `AutoSize` to true.
- Calculate the area using the single-line
  comment's dimensions.
- Calculate the new dimensions by adjusting the
  single-line comment's area to a 3x4 aspect ration (or whatever aspect
  ratio looks better).

The problem with this approach is that for longer comments, and especially comments with line breaks, this leaves **white space** at the **bottom**.

Is there a way to **adjust** the comment **height** so there is no (or, at least, not too much) white space? Like detecting if the last letter of the comment is visible and if not adjust the size? Or use something else?

By trial and error I pretty much figured out by how much I can adjust the comment height based on the amount of text (or more accurately, the length or area of the single-line auto-sized comment), which is about 0.7 for shorter comments and 0.52 for long ones (using the default fonts/etc). But throwing in **line breaks** makes it even more complex (I figured it's about 25% of text for each line break, not counting the title line break). I want to make it more accurate and less fragile (in case it breaks for a different font/etc).

If there is a better way? I'm open to any ideas, as long as it's not a single line (for longer comments), it does not leave a lot of unnecessary white space, and the comment text is not cropped (I do not care if text is cropped to the right by the Excel spreadsheet's border).

Here is my macro:

```
Sub AutoSizeCommentInSelectedCellTest()
    Dim cellComment As Comment  ' selected cell
    Dim area As Double          ' comment rectangle area

    Const MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH = 300

    ' Make sure we have a seected cell.
    If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Make sure we have a comment in the selected cell.
    Set cellComment = ActiveCell.Comment

    If cellComment Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With cellComment
        With .Shape
            ' AutoSize will covert comment to a single line.
            .TextFrame.AutoSize = True

            ' If comment's width is shorter than max, we're done.
            If .width < MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' Calculate area of the comment text rectangle
            ' for a single-line comment.
            area = .width * .height

            ' Make new comment area roughly 4h x 3w.
            .width = (VBA.Sqr(area / 12)) * 3
            .height = (VBA.Sqr(area / 12)) * 4

            ' Now, for longer comments, and especially comments
            ' with line break, this leaves a lot of white space
            ' at the bottom. How do we fix it?
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the comment has line breaks, it is not auto-sized to a single line... It may be easier to simply add one if there are x characters without one... if you get what I mean... but I will run some tests myself (can't remember problems with auto size)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel: Hmmm... Maybe it's not auto-sizing to a single line, but it definitely resizes the comment (since I resize it based on the new area dimensions). I'll run some tests. (Man, why do they not work like tooltips in any other windows program? Or at least had an API to determine the area taken by text!)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel: Yes, you're correct: it converts each paragraph to a single line, but there are multiple lines (one for each paragraph). I'm wondering if I can convert new lines to some special character combination, auto-size, then convert them back to new lines.

Comment: Nope, can't replace: it breaks comment formatting (making everything bold, I think, after the author's title formatting).

Answer (score 1):

I made modifications to the code provided above and I believe the following is more refined and cleaned up.  It also has comments that better explain what and why of each step.  I have tested it several times and appears to work very well for its intended purpose of modifying a comment box to a **fixed max width** and **adjusting height automatically** to a size where all text is viewable without too much extra space.  I set the width to `250`.

```
Sub AutoSizeCommentBox()
Dim cellComment As Comment      'Comment object
Dim textArr As Variant          'Comment text deliminted to string array
Dim elements As Integer         'textArr Upper Bound
Dim textWidthArr() As Integer   'Array of length of each element of textArr array
Dim maxLine As Integer          'Max line length from textWidthArr array, then modified
Dim lineHeight As Single        'Height of each line, stated in points (not pixels)
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction     'Shorten the way WorksheetFunction is called
Set wf = WorksheetFunction      'Set wf as the key word WorksheetFunction
Dim linesNeeded As Integer      'Lines needed to increase comment box height

Const MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH = 250

'Exit sub if no cell is active
If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set cellComment = ActiveCell.Comment
'Exit sub if no comment exists in active cell.
If cellComment Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

With cellComment
    'AutoSize comment box
    .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    'Exit sub if comment box width is shorter than max
    If .Shape.Width < MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'textArray becomes string array deliminated by Linefeed Characters [Chr(10)]
        'or in other words, by each line in comment
    textArr = Split(.Text, Chr(10))
    'Save upper bound of textArr array
    elements = UBound(textArr)
    'Set upper bound of textWidthArr array to same as textArr array
    ReDim textWidthArr(elements)
    For e = 0 To elements
        'puts the length of each line from textArr array into textWidthArr array
        textWidthArr(e) = Len(textArr(e))
    Next e
    'Grabs the max line length
    maxLine = wf.Max(textWidthArr)
    With .Shape
        'Calculates the height of each line (adjusted up 1) in points
        lineHeight = .Height / (elements + 1)
        'Adjust maxLine length (width)
        maxLine = wf.RoundDown(maxLine * (MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH / .Width), 0) * 0.9
        For e = 0 To elements
            If textWidthArr(e) = 0 Then
                'No width lines need only one line
                linesNeeded = linesNeeded + 1
            Else
                'Wider original lines need more lines
                linesNeeded = linesNeeded + wf.RoundUp(textWidthArr(e) / maxLine, 0)
            End If
        Next e
        .Width = MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH
        .Height = linesNeeded * lineHeight
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some mistake.  With .Shape  is missed.

```
Sub AutoSizeCommentInSelectedCell()
    Dim cellComment As Comment  ' selected cell
    Dim area As Double          ' comment rectangle area
    Dim n As Integer, vS As Variant
    Dim myMax As Integer, base As Single, rowLen As Integer
    Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim vR(), rowCnt As Integer, myHeight As Single

    Set Wf = WorksheetFunction

    Const MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH = 300

    ' Make sure we have a seected cell.
    If ActiveCell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Make sure we have a comment in the selected cell.
    Set cellComment = ActiveCell.Comment

    If cellComment Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With cellComment
        'myLen = Len(.Text)

        vS = Split(.Text, Chr(10))
        ReDim vR(UBound(vS))
        For i = 0 To UBound(vS)
            vR(i) = Len(vS(i))
        Next i
        myMax = Wf.Max(vR)
        n = UBound(vS)
        ' AutoSize will covert comment to a single line.
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        ' If comment's width is shorter than max, we're done.
        With .Shape
            base = .Height / (n + 1)
            rowLen = Wf.RoundDown(myMax * (300 / .Width), 0) 'row character's length when width 300
            rowLen = rowLen - rowLen * 0.1 '<~~line character's number  is more small. 
            For i = 0 To n
                If Len(vS(i)) = 0 Then
                    rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
                Else
                    rowCnt = rowCnt + Wf.RoundUp(Len(vS(i)) / rowLen, 0)
                End If
            Next i
            myHeight = rowCnt * base

            If .Width < MAX_COMMENT_WIDTH Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            .Width = 300
            .Height = myHeight
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good catch, Dy.Lee (I stripped a bit too much code from my original for this sample). I'll adjust the post. It's not the primary issue, though. Adding the With statement fixes the compilation bug, but it does not address the original problem.

Comment: It does work fine for short comments, but try it with a comment that has, say, 3-4 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum text.

Comment: @AlekDavis: I added some trick in my answer.  That is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work. I don't even understand why it would work (logically). For a long comment (say, 3 paragraphs) with the area of 444841 and 19 line breaks, the calculated height is ~770, more than half of it is taken by white space. Subtracting 19 from 770 makes no difference.

Comment: @AlekDavis, I modified my answer.  It is little in correct.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work (clips off text for longer comments with line breaks).

Comment: @AlekDavis:  there is line character number loss rate. I added this to code.

Comment: I'll check tomorrow, but I'm 99.99% sure it will not work. I do not think there is a way to reliably determine "character number loss" for text with blank lines. Just due to the nature of the problem. Say, your longest line is 1000 characters, and then you have 100 lines half of which are blank lines and another half has lass than 50 characters. You need to do pretty extensive research to determine the multiplier and in code account for the number of characters in each line as compared to the longest line. So it'd be a loot of calculations and a lot of messy code.

Comment: @AlekDavis: Best of luck to you.